# Evaluating if two ConditionSets are disjoint in sympy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

In sympy, it is trivial to evaluate whether two Intervals are disjoint

```
In [3]: from sympy import Interval

In [4]: Interval(0, 2).is_disjoint(Interval(-2, -1))
Out[4]: True

In [5]: Interval(0, 2).is_disjoint(Interval(1, 2))
Out[5]: False

In [6]: Interval(0, 2).intersect(Interval(-2, -1))
Out[6]: EmptySet
```

However in the case when I have two ConditionSet objects, how can I perform the is_disjoint check ?

```
In [12]: from sympy import ConditionSet, Symbol, S

In [13]: x = Symbol('x')

In [14]: ConditionSet(x, x >1, S.Reals).is_disjoint(ConditionSet(x, x < 1, S.Reals))
Out[14]: False

In [15]: ConditionSet(x, x >1, S.Reals).intersect(ConditionSet(x, x < 1, S.Reals))
Out[15]: Intersection(ConditionSet(x, x > 1, Reals), ConditionSet(x, x < 1, Reals))
```

`is_disjoint` simply checks if `intersect` equates to `EmptySet` and in the case of the ConditionSet the `intersect` is still not evaluated.

What is the best way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way:

```
In [4]: s = ConditionSet(x, x >1, S.Reals).intersect(ConditionSet(x, x < 1, S.Reals))

In [5]: s.as_relational(y)
Out[5]: y > 1 ∧ -∞ < y ∧ y < 1 ∧ y < ∞

In [6]: s.as_relational(y).simplify()
Out[6]: False
```

Comment: Thank you, as a follow-up question, if you permit: in the case when an intersection does exit like


```
In [21]: s = ConditionSet(x, x >1, S.Reals).intersect(ConditionSet(x, x > 1, S.Reals))

In [22]: s.as_relational(y).simplify()
Out[22]: (y > 1) & (y < oo)

In [23]: type(_)
Out[23]: And
```


How can I convert Out to an Interval?

Comment: You can use `.as_set()`.